# AngularJS escaping quotes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, escaping

I am having a hard time escaping quotes in from the following statement

`on-mouseover="mouseover('{{landmark.name}}')"`
where `landmark.name="Duke's Car"`

I tried various solutions like:

```
    $scope.escapeQuotes= function(str) {
    return str 
        .replace(/('|\")/g, "\\$1")
        .replace(/("|\")/g, "\\$1")
    }
```

But it does not seem to work. Looks like a simple problem but I am having a hard time finding a solution. Any pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say use `ng-mouseover` instead, you don't need to worry about that escaping things

```
ng-mouseover="mouseover(landmark.name)"
```

**Code**

```
$scope.mouseover = function(name){
   console.log("Value output:", name)
}
```

Comment: Good answer but I am drawing a circle from ng-maps and ng-mouseover does not seem to work with that so I have to use on-mouseover. Secondly what is the difference between using {{landmark.name}} and entering it directly like Landmark.name. So what does adding {{}} solve. Because removing {{}} seemed to fix my problem.

Comment: `{{expression}}` means you are evaluating expression with respect to scope specified in brackets.

Comment: I didn't actually seen that you were mentioned that you are tend to use it in map..

Answer (score 1):

Pankaj's answer is better but if you absolutely need to use `on-mousever`, you can replace single and double quotation marks with their HTML entities which will prevent them from breaking the outer quotes of the `mousever` function call:

```
on-mouseover="mouseover(\"{{ landmark.name.replace(/'/g, "&apos;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;") }}\")"
```

Then `landmark.name` can safely contain single or quotes and it won't cause any problems.

So if `landmark.name` equals `Duke's Car", your HTML would renderlike this (after Angular compiles it):

```
on-mousever="mouseover(\"Duke&apos;s Car\")"
```

Whenever this is rendered by the browser, the `&apos;` HTML entity will become a single quotation mark: `'`

Comment: then it would be break if `"` in there in `name`, correct?

Comment: You're correct.  I updated the answer to have it search/replace both single and double quotes and replace them with their HTML entities: &apos; and &quot;

Comment: Cool.. +1 for unescaping